# NSArray, NSUserDefaults, optionals and unwrapping mess

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I have really nasty errors while working with something apparently simple.

I have an `NSArray` which I fill with words the first time the app launches.

Then at a certain point I want to use the array, so I declared another array inside the class:

`var localArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("array")!`

Then I want to display a word in a label. And when a user presses a button (forward/backward) the next/previous word appears. Pretty simple, right? It is, but somehow I get really nasty errors.

I have 2 methods for the next/previous words:

```
    @IBAction func nextWord(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let currentIndex = localArray.indexOf(label.text!)
        {
            if currentIndex == localArray.count-1
            {
                label.text = localArray[0] as? String
            }
            else
            {
                label.text = localArray[currentIndex+1]
            }
        }
    }
```

The other method for going backwards is identical (with necessary modifications).

And in `viewDidLoad` I just set the label's text:

```
label.text = localArray[0] as? String
```

The problem is with the `if let` statements. Before using the user defaults, I just initialized `localArray` with a few strings. And everything worked fine. But once I added the user defaults, madness began. I had errors everywhere I used `localArray` saying that the array isn't unwrapped. So I added `!` after the user defaults array when initializing the local one.

But the last 2 errors (in the `if let` statements) make no sense. Now the `indexOf()` method throws an error, a thing that didn't happen before. And it also tells me that it can't convert the string (label.text!) to `@noescape (AnyObject) throws -> Bool`.

So now I need to transform that string to an `NSString` for that to work or what? I found something about "bridging" related to arrays in user defaults. Is that my issue?

Now here's what bugs me: WHY do I have to explicitly downcast a string in the array to a string? WHY did the `indexOf` method change.

Doesn't an unwrapped optional act like a non-optional?

Comment: Is this pure Swift code? You shouldn't be using `NSArray` at all in that case. Use the native collection types instead, which you can freely bridge to `NSArray` to store in `NSUserDefaults` (as long as the elements are obj-c bridgeable).

Comment: It's Swift only. What do you mean by using native collection types?

Comment: Well... the [collection types that Swift itself provides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105)!  If you want an array of strings, then you want `[String]`. `String` can be freely bridged to `NSString`, so you can freely bridge the array to `NSArray`.

Comment: Well that's what the array is before I put it in the user defaults. Then I use `.setObject` to set the array in the user defaults. I think that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you are creating is not an array (at least the compiler doesn't know it is).  The function `arrayForKey("array")!` is returning an `AnyObject`, not an `Array`.  So from there on out the compiler thinks this object is an `AnyObject`.  How I would solve this (may not be the correct way) would be to cast the Array immediately:

```
if let myArray: AnyObject! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("array") {
    //Your array exists, cast it now and use it
    var localArray =  myArray as! Array<String>
}
else
{
    //Something bad happened, the array isn't there.
}
```

Then you will have to do unwrapping later on.  If you know this object will always exist and the cast will always work you can change the `?` to `!`.

Look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24585226/1671729) for a little more information.

Comment: Wrap it in an if statement and put your error handling in the else part.

Comment: Try the code now, I edited it to use exactly what the answer I referenced used.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine now. I want the `localArray` to be a global variable. How can I do that instead of adding your code in 3 separate places?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot better if it were implemented with the modulo operator.

`let newIndex = (oldIndex + 1) % localArray.count`

I need more information to answer the bulk of your question. What's the type of the `localArray`?

Comment: I didn't specify it. But it should be `NSArray`. What should I replace to use `newIndex`? It's still using `currentIndex` so it fixes nothing.

Comment: I renamed `currentIndex` for clarity.

Comment: What do you mean "I didn't specify it. But it should be NSArray"? You put that array in the user defaults, what type is it? I'm not asking what it **should** be, frankly, that's irrelevant. What **is** it?

Comment: You asked about `localArray`. That one is initialized in the scene. The one which I put in the user defaults is `[String]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should always [avoid force unwrapping optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) (and for the most-part force downcasting). In order to safely retrieve your array from `NSUserDefaults` (with the correct type), you can do the following:

```
if let array = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("array") as? [String] {
    // do something with your [String] array
} else {
    // do error handling
}
```

What this will do is get an `[AnyObject]?` from `NSUserDefaults`, representing your array. You can then use `as?` to conditionally downcast & bridge it back over to a Swift array of strings (`[String]`). If this was unsuccessful, you can safely handle that eventuality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It clarified my situation.